# Having a bit of trouble with MySQL query to receive random combinations from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join, random, limit

This was the original question:

> Alright, here is my issue, I have two
>   tables, one named firstnames and the
>   other named lastnames. What I am
>   trying to do here is to find 100 of
>   the possible combinations from these
>   names for test data. The firstnames
>   table has 5494 entries in a single
>   column, and the lastnames table has
>   88799 entries in a single column. The
>   only query that I have been able to
>   come up with that has some results is:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM
>     (SELECT * FROM firstnames ORDER BY rand()) f
>     LEFT JOIN
>          (SELECT * FROM lastnames 
> ORDER BY rand()) l ON 1=1 limit 10;    The problem with this code is
> ```
>
> that it  selects 1 firstname and gives
>   every  lastname that could go with it.
>   While  this is plausible, I will have
>   to set  the limit to 500000000 in
>   order to get  all the combinations
>   possible without  having only 20 first
>   names(and I'd  rather not kill my
>   server). However, I  only need 100
>   random generations of  entries for
>   test data, and I will not  be able to
>   get that with this code.  Can anyone
>   please give me any advice?

- The above question has already been answered, I need advice on the question below. I am just providing it as a background.

I want to join another table to the mix named status. This table has 5 entries in one column, and whenever I attempt to join it to the other two, it ends up repeating the two other tables over again so that the status tags fit with every one of them. The only one that I am getting mild success with is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT firstnames FROM firstnames ORDER BY RAND( )  LIMIT 5 ) AS First
JOIN ( SELECT lastnames FROM lastnames ORDER BY RAND( )  LIMIT 5 ) as Last 
JOIN ( SELECT status FROM status ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 1) AS Status ON 1=1;
```

While the first and last names do not repeat in this query, only one status tag is listed with each of them. Thank you guys very much for your help!

Comment: Do the tables have an `id` field (primary key)?

Comment: No, they do not. I originally did have them on each table, but it created a mess.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506709/mysql-query-to-receive-random-combinations-from-two-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MySQL Variables, you should be able to accomplish via something like...  Although not explicitly tested, this SHOULD get you what you want.  You can't do a simple Cartesian cross-join because as you know it will get the first FirstName and join with ALL the Last Names, then the NEXT First Name with all the last names...

This query uses MySQL variables.  The inner query (pre respective first and last names) will pre-query your random 10 first (or last) names.  Then, join that to a @variable for first name sequence (@fns) and last name sequence (@lns).  Since both will have only 10 records, and each will both start with their counter at 0, they will BOTH result in records with a sequence from 1-10 and thus the JOIN will be on the SEQUENCE where only one of each guaranteed value will occur... vs rand() which returns some floating point fraction where you are never guaranteed a number from one table will match that of another.

```
select
      First10.FirstName,
      Last10.LastName,
      ( SELECT status FROM status ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 1) AS Status
   from 
      ( select fn.FirstName,
               @fns := @fns + 1 as Sequence
           from
             ( select FirsName,
                  from FirstNames
                  order by rand() 
                  limit 10 ) fn,
             (select @fns := 0 ) vars
      ) First10

      JOIN

      ( select ln.LastName,
               @lns := @lns + 1 as Sequence
           from
              ( select LastName,
                   from LastNames
                   order by rand() 
                   limit 10 ) ln,
              (select @lns := 0 ) vars 
      ) Last10

      ON First10.Sequence = Last10.Sequence
```

Comment: This is much nicer for the original query I needed for the previous question. Thank you very much!

However, now I need to add that status table to the mix.

Comment: @ypercube, thanks... I've found MySQL variables to come in QUITE handy to MANY solutions... and have used in a variety of COMPLEX solutions offered here at S/O.

Comment: @michael; Juat add `JOIN ( SELECT status FROM status ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS Status` in the end. Then all 100 rows will have same (random) status.

Comment: @Michael, just add that as a FIELD level select (as I've updated the answer)

Comment: Got it guys, you've helped a bunch. You have my gratitude :)

Answer (score 0):

I would first add an (automunbered) id field on both tables.

Then I would write a stored procedure that:

- Creates a temporary table `randomid` with 2 fields (firstid, lastid).
- Inserts 100 rows (or the number you need) with random integers in the two fields, (from 1 to MAX(firstnames.id) into the first field and from 1 to MAX(lastnames.id) to the second one).
- Joins the `firstnames` and `lastnames` tables to `randomid`
- Drops the temp table.

Comment: I already have a solution to generating the randomized names, but I need to join the status table to the other two.

Answer (score 0):

How about turning it on it's head:

```
SELECT f.name,l.name FROM lastnames l INNER JOIN firstnames f ON 1=1 ORDER BY rand() limit 100;
```

Inner joins being faster than left joins etc?

Comment: The query never came back, and I already have a solution to this part of the question. I'm trying to join the status table to the other two.

Comment: Adding status to this query would be simpler than using sub selects

Comment: It will try to create in memory the `CROSS JOIN` of the two tables before doing the `ORDER BY RAND()`. Which means 500M rows in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your status table does, but this will get you random names:

```
select firstnames, lastnames
from (select firstnames from firstnames order by rand() limit 100) fn
cross join (select lastnames from lastnames order by rand() limit 100) ln
order by rand()
limit 100;
```

The aliased selects are there so the query returns in this lifetime - there are 10000 rows in the cross join... manageable. Without them there would be gazillions of rows - query wouldn't come back with your row counts

Comment: The status table is meant to randomly label the randomized names by a tag. Eg. Alive, Dead, etc. There are 5 rows in total for that.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the status problem:

```
SELECT
    First.firstnames firstname
    Last.lastnames lastname
    ( SELECT status FROM status ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ) status
FROM 
    ( SELECT firstnames FROM firstnames ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 5 ) First
    JOIN ( SELECT lastnames FROM lastnames ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 5 ) Last
```